# Apache service not starting

Tags: server, apache2

While trying to install apache version 2.4.4 using the following method:

<sub>Source: http://zhuojun.info/?p=1121</sub>

> Before installing Apache 2.4.4, you should install PCRE, otherwise it will not succeed. The process of installing PCRE is simple. After you downloaded it, run in terminal next commands:
>
> ```
> sudo ./configure
> sudo make
> sudo make install
> ```
>
> Download APR and APR-Util from http://apr.apache.org, unpack them to Apache directory, `/srclib/apr` and `/srclib/apr-util` (no version numbers in the directory names) and type following commands to install Apache:
>
> ```
> sudo ./configure --with-included-apr
> sudo make
> sudo make install
> ```
>
> Type following command to start Apache:
>
> ```
> sudo /usr/local/apache2/bin/apachectl start
> ```
>
> There may be something wrongs like:
>
> ```
> /usr/local/apache2/bin/httpd: error while loading shared libraries: libpcre.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
> ```
>
> Type following command to see httpd’s shared library dependencies:
>
> ```
> ldd httpd
> ```
>
> Found "libpcre.so.1 => not found", then type the following command to update links:
>
> ```
> sudo ldconfig
> ```
>
> Restart Apache and should work.

Everything seemed fine but when I tried to start the apache service it gives error:

```
root@server1:/usr/local/apache2/bin# /etc/init.d/apache2 start
 * Starting web server apache2                                                  /usr/sbin/apache2: symbol lookup error: /usr/sbin/apache2: undefined symbol: apr_ldap_url_parse
Action 'start' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
                                                                         [fail]
```

I tried to install the apr again but nothing seems to work. Please help.

The Apache log shows something like this:

```
[Mon Jun 17 10:31:08 2013] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.3.10-1ubuntu3.6 with Suhosin-Patch configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Jun 17 11:48:20 2013] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.3.10-1ubuntu3.6 with Suhosin-Patch configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Jun 17 15:44:36 2013] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.3.10-1ubuntu3.6 with Suhosin-Patch configured -- resuming normal operations
```

Comment: It does sound like it didn't find the APR files when it was building. You definitely unpacked the APR and APR-Util sources into the `srclib` directory within your Apache source directory, and ran `sudo ./configure --with-included-apr` after that, build makeing Apache?

Comment: I made the directory name /srclib and extracted the apr and apr-util in it inside directories /srclib/apr and srclib/apr-util and started building the apache it was completed and while starting it gave the error and I rectified it by the method above but now Im stuck with this apr error.

Comment: Unless I am misunderstanding you, it sounds like you have created a directory called `srclib` in the root of your filesystem. I think you need to put the directories extracted from the APR and APR-Util downloads in the `srclib` directory of the `httpd-2.4.4` directory, before running `sudo ./configure --with-included-apr` followed by  make.

Comment: Ya I have made the directory /srclib in the root of my filesystem i.e. '/' and the contents extracted from the tar file of apr and apr-util in /srclib/apr and srclib/apr-util and not in the httpd-2.4.4 directory.

Comment: @David: Where should I extract the contents of the httpd-2.4.4.tar.gz file any specific directory or anywhere?

Comment: It shouldn't matter where you put the contents of httpd-2.4.4.tar.gz so long as you put the contents of apr-1.4.6.tar.gz apr-util-1.5.2.tar.gz inside the `srclib` directory inside the extracted `httpd-2.4.4` directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your comments, it appears that Apache is failing to start because it did not find APR when it was compiled. This is because the source files were not in the correct place when `configure` was run. You need to:

- Extract the APR and APR-Util into the `srclib` directory within the `httpd-2.4.4` directory.
- `cd` to the `httpd-2.4.4` directory and run:

  `sudo ./configure --with-included-apr`

  `sudo make`

  `sudo make install`